# How does Xarray plot a bar chart?

Tags: python, plot, python-xarray

How can I plot a bar chart from a Python Xarray dataset (eg. rain data axis)?

I am already using this code to resize the plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9)) #redimensionamento do gráfico
dsfanadia.rain.plot(ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to make a bar chart with xarray is to convert your data into pandas:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 9))
series = dsfanadia.to_series()
series.plot.bar(ax=ax)
```